# Image of a normal Hall Subgroup under an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group such that $|G|= n = md$, where $\gcd(m,d)=1$. 
Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with order $m$.

Further, let us define a subgroup $H$ of order $d$. I managed to prove that, $H \cap N= [e] \implies HN = G$, and $HN \cong H \times N$.

Now, let $f$ be an automorphism of $G$.

Then, $|f(N)|= m$.

Consider that for some $n_i \in N$,

$f(n_i^m)= f(n_i)^m \implies f(e) = e = (f(n_i))^m$

So, the order of $f(n_i)$ divides $m$.

As $f(n_i) \in G$, $f(n_i) \in h_i N$, for some $h_i \in H$. So, let, $f(n_j) = h_i n_i \implies (h_in_i)^m = e$.

Now, consider a bijective map $g: HN \to H \times N$, such that,

$f(h_i n_i) = (h_i, n_i) \implies f((h_i n_i)^m)= f(e)= (h_i, n_i)^m= (h_i^m, n_i^m)$

$\implies (h_i^m, n_i^m)= (e, e) \implies h_i^m= e$ which is simply not possible given that $h_i \in H$ and that $gcd(m,d)=1$, unless, $h_i = e$.

So, for all $n_i \in N, f(n_i) \in N \implies f(N) = N$.

Okay, well, can somebody please just look through this reasoning and see if this is acceptable? Also, it seemed somewhat unnecessarily wordy. How could I prove it with greater brevity?

Thank you!

Comment: Under you hypotheses, you *cannot* prove that $HN \cong H \times N$ (that is, that also $H$ is normal in $G$), as the example of $S_{3}$ shows.

Comment: What did you think you proved exactly? I just see you stop at some point and say 'okay, well that's how I proved it' but I don't see what your claim is.

Comment: You have way too many implication arrows. This is bad form. *Write more text*.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva I forgot to mention it. Basically, I was to prove, that if N is a normal subgroup of G with an order that is coprime to its index, then, for any automorphism, the image of N is N itself.

Comment: @kahen Noted. I shall keep that in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Even more is true. If the group has such a subgroup then it is the unique subgroup of that order and it will contain any subgroup whose order divides the given order. I think I wrote a proof of this somewhere here, but finding it and linking it is a bit cumbersome as I am on a tablet.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, my proofs below should give the more general statement you quote.

Comment: Perhaps also note that the correct title would be *Image of a **normal** Hall subgroup under an automorphism*. A non-normal Hall subgroup is of course not invariant even under *inner* automorphisms.

Comment: One problem in your reasoning is that you simply state "Further, let us define a subgroup H of order d."! How do you know that such a subgroup exists (it does)? You should either prove its existence or refer to some theorem that proves it [Or better: you don't need such a subgroup as Andreas showed].

Comment: @j.p. I thought so, yes. That was a tentative assumption. But given the existence of such a subgroup, is the rest of the reasoning acceptable?

Comment: @MWarsi, as I said above, in your argument you assume your group is a direct product $N \times H$, which is not necessarily the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. One is to note that
$$
\lvert N f(N) \rvert = \frac{\lvert N \rvert \cdot \lvert f(N) \rvert}{\lvert N \cap f(N) \rvert}.
$$
So this number is a multiple of $m$, a divisor of $n = m d$, and of $\lvert N \rvert \cdot \lvert f(N) \rvert = m^{2}$, and thus coprime to $d$. The only choice is 
$$
\lvert N f(N) \rvert = m = \lvert N \rvert,
$$
so $f(N) \subseteq N$, and thus $f(N) = N$.

Alternatively, I think you are proving that
$$\tag{eq}
N = \{ x \in G : x^{m} = 1 \},
$$
which immediately implies that $N$ is invariant under automorphisms (even endomorphisms).

(eq) follows from the fact that if $x^m = 1$, then $(x N)^m = N$ in $G/N$, but since the order of $G/N$ is $d$, you also have $(xN)^d = N$, and since $(m, d) = 1$, we have $x N = N$, that is, $x \in N$.

---

**PS** The second way of doing it proves the statement that **@TobiasKildetoft** made in his comment. The first way works too, just take any subgroup $M$ of order dividing $m$, and consider $\lvert N M \rvert$, to obtain $M \le N$.

Comment: Yes, probably the easiest way to do it.

Comment: Wow. That's pretty neat. Thanks a bunch!